# Как скрыть ссылку в коде?

Tags: php, javascript, html, .htaccess

В коде html или php (не важно), требуется скрыть ссылку. Скрыть не в отображении, а прямо в коде, чтобы не смогли увидеть исходного кода.

Может есть скрипты какие или какие-либо другие способы решения?

Comment: Ссылка должна остаться рабочей?

Comment: Сами то понимаете, что пишете? Нельзя так сделать.

Answer (score 4):

Совершенно непонятно зачем вам нужно скрывать от посторонних глаз именно ссылку - то, что априори должно быть известно клиенту. Любой запрос, который будет выполнен браузером, не важно, путем нажатия пользователем на ссылку либо путем "скрытого" запроса по ajax, может быть отслежен.

Вся та логика, в которую клиент вникать не должен, должна выполняться на сервере. Опишите подробнее, чего вы хотите достичь этим действием.